# Convert Akamai Edgescape header data into array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using Akamai to detect Geolocation. Akamai returns the following data in the header:

```
X-Akamai-Edgescape: georegion=279,country_code=US,region_code=OR,city=BEAVERTON,dma=820,pmsa=6440,msa=6442,areacode=503,county=WASHINGTON,fips=41067,lat=45.4908,long=-122.8046,timezone=PST,zip=97005-97008+97075-97077,continent=NA,throughput=vhigh,bw=5000,network=comcast,asnum=33490,network_type=cable,location_id=0
```

I'm converting this data into an array using PHP explode.

```
Array
(
  [0] => georegion=279
  [1] => country_code=US
  [2] => region_code=OR
  [3] => city=BEAVERTON
  [4] => dma=820
  [5] => pmsa=6440
  [6] => msa=6442
  [7] => areacode=503
  [8] => county=WASHINGTON
  [9] => fips=41067
  [10] => lat=45.4908
  [11] => long=-122.8046
  [12] => timezone=PST
  [13] => zip=97005-97008+97075-97077
  [14] => continent=NA
  [15] => throughput=vhigh
  [16] => bw=5000
  [17] => network=comcast
  [18] => asnum=33490
  [19] => network_type=cable
  [20] => location_id=0
)
```

Getting the key value pairs is pretty easy, however, in order to make this future proof I don't want to grab the values with the current keys because the order of the items returned by Akamai could be changed by them.

What's the best way to go about converting this array and/or data into something more like the following?

```
Array 
(
  georegion => 279
  country_code => US
  ...
  location_id => 0
)
```

Comment: what's wrong with just loop trough it, explode the values by `=` and build the desired array? Since it'll be only roundabout 20 entries, this should not be a performance issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to parse the string into a key value pair.

Using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and a foreach loop:

```
<?php
$str = 'georegion=279,country_code=US,region_code=OR,city=BEAVERTON,dma=820,pmsa=6440,msa=6442,areacode=503,county=WASHINGTON,fips=41067,lat=45.4908,long=-122.8046,timezone=PST,zip=97005-97008+97075-97077,continent=NA,throughput=vhigh,bw=5000,network=comcast,asnum=33490,network_type=cable,location_id=0';

$array = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $v = explode('=', $value);
    $array[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php
$str = 'georegion=279,country_code=US,region_code=OR,city=BEAVERTON,dma=820,pmsa=6440,msa=6442,areacode=503,county=WASHINGTON,fips=41067,lat=45.4908,long=-122.8046,timezone=PST,zip=97005-97008+97075-97077,continent=NA,throughput=vhigh,bw=5000,network=comcast,asnum=33490,network_type=cable,location_id=0';

$array = explode(',', $str);

array_map(function ($value, $key) use (&$array) {
    $v = explode('=', $value);
    $array[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    unset($array[$key]);
}, $array, array_keys($array));
```

Using regex to match key and value, then [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
<?php
$str = 'georegion=279,country_code=US,region_code=OR,city=BEAVERTON,dma=820,pmsa=6440,msa=6442,areacode=503,county=WASHINGTON,fips=41067,lat=45.4908,long=-122.8046,timezone=PST,zip=97005-97008+97075-97077,continent=NA,throughput=vhigh,bw=5000,network=comcast,asnum=33490,network_type=cable,location_id=0';

preg_match_all("/([^,=]+)=([^,=]+)/", $str, $matches); 
$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to switch `,` for `&`, then [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
<?php
$str = 'georegion=279,country_code=US,region_code=OR,city=BEAVERTON,dma=820,pmsa=6440,msa=6442,areacode=503,county=WASHINGTON,fips=41067,lat=45.4908,long=-122.8046,timezone=PST,zip=97005-97008+97075-97077,continent=NA,throughput=vhigh,bw=5000,network=comcast,asnum=33490,network_type=cable,location_id=0';

parse_str(str_replace(",", "&", $str), $array);
```

All methods will produce the same array structure:

```
Array
(
    [georegion] => 279
    [country_code] => US
    [region_code] => OR
    [city] => BEAVERTON
    [dma] => 820
    [pmsa] => 6440
    [msa] => 6442
    [areacode] => 503
    [county] => WASHINGTON
    [fips] => 41067
    [lat] => 45.4908
    [long] => -122.8046
    [timezone] => PST
    [zip] => 97005-97008+97075-97077
    [continent] => NA
    [throughput] => vhigh
    [bw] => 5000
    [network] => comcast
    [asnum] => 33490
    [network_type] => cable
    [location_id] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you Lawrence, that's perfect! I was wrestling with this one for awhile yesterday.